# Potassium ethoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, alkali-metals

Is it possible to make potassium ethoxide by mixing $\ce{KOH}$ and $\ce{EtOH}$ in the presence of a dehydrating agent like $\ce{MgSO4}$ or $\ce{CaO}$ or $\ce{K2CO3}$?

The easy way is adding metallic potassium to ethanol. But nobody likes to deal with potassium or hydrogen.

My understanding is that added $\ce{KOH}$ reacts with $\ce{EtOH}$ in a reversible way. But if there is a water absorber the product water is gone so the reaction moves to the right side.

$$\ce{C2H5OH + KOH <=> C2H5OK + H2O}$$

Comment: Better way is buy it: [Sigma-Aldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/333379?lang=en&region=US) sells it in 95% pure form for USD 39.90/100 g.

Comment: What about ethanol being absorbed?